# Adding a hyphen to cells in an ISSN column in Open Refine

Tags: replace, transform, grel

Does anyone know the correct GREL for transforming cells in a column so that instead of '12456789' the string shows '1245-6789'? I want to apply this to all the different values of the cells in the column. Thanks

I was going to use the Edit Facet Expression based on Column.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a regular expression that will look for strings of eight number characters and replace them with the new format. According to the [GREL documentation](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#find-and-replace) and this [forum post](https://groups.google.com/g/openrefine/c/W-QtZ4EOCsA/m/iOT0EzzGBQAJ), one way to do that is as follows:

```js
'12456789'.replace(/(\n{4})(\n{4})/, "$1-$2")
```

This works by taking a capture group of the first four numbers and a capture group of the final four numbers, then replacing that string with a string that has a hyphen between the two groups.